# Ruby idiom: method call or else default

Tags: ruby, methods, default, idioms

What's the proper way of doing this in Ruby?

```
def callOrElse(obj, method, default)
  if obj.respond_to?(method) 
     obj.__send__(method)
  else 
     default
  end
end
```

Comment: Is EAFP (i.e. use try-except here) not embraced in the Ruby community the way it is by Pythonistas?

Comment: @Karl. I am not talking for all Rubyist, but having to write (at least) four lines for something you could do in one is definitely  annoying for many Ruby programmers (something they probably wouldn't mind in Python, though).

Comment: Moreover, I wouldn't use a try/except construct here if what the OP intends includes a __default__ behavior. In my opinion, if both ways (i.e. `send` and `default`) can occur, why make it an "Exception"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it hasn't been offered as an answer:

```
result = obj.method rescue default
```

As with @slhck, I probably wouldn't use this when I knew there was a reasonable chance that obj won't respond to method, but it is an option.

Comment: Simple as it is, this has the major drawback of shadowing any exception that obj.method raises, you won't know if it had no method or it just failed. I personally would avoid inplace rescues whenever possible.

Comment: -1 For the reason that @tokland mentioned. You really can't use this as a general strategy.

Answer (score 3):

So you want something similar to `x = obj.method || default`? Ruby is an ideal language to build your own bottom-up constructions:

```
class Object
  def try_method(name, *args, &block)
    self.respond_to?(name) ? self.send(name, *args, &block) : nil     
  end
end

p "Hello".try_method(:downcase) || "default" # "hello"
p "hello".try_method(:not_existing) || "default" # "default"
```

Maybe you don't like this indirect calling with symbols? no problem, then look at [Ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/)'s `maybe` style and use a proxy object (you can figure out the implementation):

```
p "hello".maybe_has_method.not_existing || "default" # "default"
```

Side note: I am no OOP expert, but it's my understanding that you should know whether the object you are calling has indeed such method beforehand. Or is `nil` the object you want to control not to send methods to? Im this case Ick is already a nice solution: `object_or_nil.maybe.method || default`

Comment: This is generally a good answer, but note that the implementation will result in any existing method that returns `false` or `nil` having the "default" used instead.

Comment: @Phrogz: that's a good point, but it's unlikely you need a default value in this case, just write the condition "if obj.maybe.enabled?". Anyway, you can always tweak the maybe pattern to your needs: "obj.maybe(:default => true).active?", but "|| default" should cover the typical cases.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go for

```
obj.respond_to?(method) ? obj.__send__(method) : default
```

Comment: This is much cleaner, but is essentially the same functionality. I thought there would be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Well, what do you want if not the same _functionality_? :) As far as I am concerned, there's no way to bypass this decision. But maybe somebody has an idea.

Comment: I was hoping for something like: `x = obj.method || default`.

Comment: If you really want that, you could override `method_missing` to return `nil`, but I would advise against that.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
object&.method(n) || 'default'
```

the '&' acts as a Maybe here. Maybe it has something, maybe it doesn't. Of course, if it doesn't, it will just return nil and would not run the method that comes after it.

Comment: Is this a new version thing or `rails` thing? Tried it on pry but it says `NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object`

Comment: @Tiw The safe navigation operator, `&.`, was added in Ruby 2.3. It isn't appropriate here though, it is meant to be used to avoid `nil` checks not general missing methods (i.e. `o&.m` is `o.nil? ? nil : o.m`, not `o.respond_to?(:m) ? o.m : nil`).

Comment: @muistooshort  Got it, thanks for explaining it to me :)

Comment: @Tiw is right. It's used to avoid nil checks. Regardless, the best pattern for something like this is to use the [Strategy pattern](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/05/strategy-design-pattern-in-ruby/)